# Special Character in XML Attribute Value

Tags: xml

I want to put a colon in an attribute value that is used to display the title of a chart on my webpage.

I have something like:

```
<chart displayname="This is the chart name"  resource = "blah blah blah">
```

I want the display name to be something like "This: is the chart name"

How can I accomplish this?

If it helps here are the HTML codes of the characters I want to use:
&#45; and &#58;

Comment: I don't get it. You can put anything in an XML attribute already.

Comment: What are you trying now, and in what way does it not work?

Comment: Actually, I had similar problems. I had a `time="2014-02-23T03:22:24.272Z"`
attribute and when I used `xmlMobile = xmlhttpData.responseXML;` it would drop the element. I changed the colons to dashes and it no longer dropped.

Answer (score 3):

Colon is not a special character.  Just put it in there, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your attributes alphanumeric, use the UTF notation instead of the colon:

```
  displayname="This&#58;My Chart"
```

Obviously the semicolon and spaces are not alphanumeric, but the above will achieve what I think you are going for.